# Fazer Upload de Imagem, e Criar um thumb da mesma Imagem Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma classe chamada imagem, onde eu tenho dois atributos, `UrlDaImagem`, e `UrlDoThumb`, eu consigo salvar a imagem, normal só que eu gostaria de cria um Thumb para essa mesma imagem, sem ter que precisar fazer um novo upload.

Classe:

```
public class Imagem
{
    [Key]
    public int ImagemId { get; set; }
    public string UrlDaImagem { get; set; }
    public string Thumb { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Produto produto, 
                           List<int> IdCategoria, 
                           HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        #region Salvar Imagem
        Imagem img = new Imagem();
        string nomeDoArquivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Arquivo.FileName);
        string extensao = Path.GetExtension(Arquivo.FileName);
        nomeDoArquivo = nomeDoArquivo + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssffff") + extensao;

        img.UrlDaImagem = "~/Imagens/Produtos/" + nomeDoArquivo;
        using (var db = new Contexto())
        {
            db.ImagemDb.Add(img);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var id = img.ImagemId;
            produto.ImagemId = id;
        }
        nomeDoArquivo = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Produtos/"),nomeDoArquivo);
        Arquivo.SaveAs(nomeDoArquivo);
        #endregion

        db.ProdutoDb.Add(produto);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Queria salvar a imagem original, e criar um `thumb`, salvar o `thumb`, e adicionar o caminho do `thumb` no banco

Comment: E qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Minha duvida é como criar um thumb, com a imagem que já está vindo no HttpPostFileBase, ou seja, com apenas essa imagem, eu quero salvar ela normal, e criar um thumb, para salvar numa pasta, e só o caminho no banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um método com o seguinte código referente a pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-thumbnail-using-asp-net

```
using ( Image bigImage = new Bitmap( filename ) )
{
   int height = bigImage.Height / 10;
   int width = bigImage.Width / 10;
   using ( Image smallImage = image.GetThumbnailImage( width, 
                                                       height,
                                                       new 
   Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(Abort), IntPtr.Zero) )
   {
      smallImage.Save("thumbnail.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
}
```

onde o `filename` é o arquivo salvo no disco.

***Referencias:***

- [Image.GetThumbnailImage(Int32, Int32, Image+GetThumbnailImageAbort, IntPtr) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_GetThumbnailImage_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Image_GetThumbnailImageAbort_System_IntPtr_)
- [Image Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)